# cvxpy gives error if launched by another user

Tags: python-3.x, conda, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I have encoutered a strange issue.
I was able to run optimisation with cvxpy.
However I passed the code to a colleague to run it.
I have python 3.7.6 he has 3.6.x.

I ask him to install the cvxpy as conda install -c conda-forge cvxpy
he did it all was going well, but when he runs the code it gets
cvxpy.error.DCPerror: problem does not follow DCP rules- Specifically the DCP is not DCP: Its following subexpressions are not:
[......] and here a list of vectors/arrays

Now how is that possible that with same code, same package cvxpy he gets the error and I do not get it?

Comment: `same package cvxpy` - did you check that both of you have the same version installed?

Comment: explicitely not, but I run for both my pc and his: conda install -c conda-forge cvxpy